# Why std::map has got bidirectional iterator type?

Tags: std, stdmap, listiterator

I'm studying different types of iterators right now. I've read that `std::map` has got `bidirectional` iterators. And `std::set`, `std::list` also have got this type of iterators. Why are they not `random access` iterators? Can anyone explain this to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard C++ library provides random access iterators to container types
for which access to an arbitrary element takes constant time, e.g. [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array),[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector),
[`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). That is because
a [*random access*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) container *is* one of
which any element can be accessed in constant time.

[`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) is not a random access container type:
access takes linear time. Neither is [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set): access
takes logarithmic time. Likewise [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).